# Modify Meta class of the default through table of a ManyToManyField from meta class in django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add some constraints to the meta class of a model that is an auto-created through model of a `ManyToManyField`. I followed the official docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/), and also implemented a meta class that sets the constraints successfully on the `Meta` class of the through model  (assured by getting `Model.many_to_many_field.through._meta.constraints` value using the Django shell itself).

The problem here is that the migration does not detect any changes on the mentioned through model hence no migration is created for the defined constraint.

The question is then, is there any way to change the meta options of a through model without implementing them explicitly?

#### Code

```py
class BarMeta(models.base.ModelBase):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        new_cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs)
        new_cls.foos.through._meta.constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(check=some_checks, name='...')
        ]
        return new_cls

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass


class Bar(models.Model, metaclass=BarMeta):
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share how you implemented the meta for the default through?

Comment: @BrianD Sure! Added the simplified code at the end of the question.